# Conversion problem from char * to wchar_t*

Tags: c++, types

The below line works. It prints Success.

```
wchar_t * s1 = (wchar_t *) L"INSERT INTO OE(sqltext) VALUES('this text')";

if(WriteToSQL(s1) == 0)
  printf( "Success");     //Success
else
  printf( "Failed");
```

I need to take user input to create dynamic sql. I need to do what 
L prefix is doing.

When i take input and do the required conversion, it does not work.

```
char input[100]; 
char sql[500];  

printf("Enter input string :: "); 
fgets(input,100,stdin); 
for(int i=0;i<100;i++) 
    if(input[i]==10) 
        input[i]=0; 

strcpy(sql,"INSERT INTO OE(sqltext) VALUES('"); 
strcat(sql,input); 
strcat(sql,"')"); 

wchar_t wsql[500];  
MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8, 0, sql, strlen(sql), 
wsql, strlen(sql) + 1 );  


if(WriteToSQL(wsql) == 0)
  printf( "Success");     
else
  printf( "Failed");     // It failed
```

---

Long conversassion but finally it did work. Hex memory dump and input from usta was most helpful. Thanks everybody for their time.

Comment: -1: Put more effort into a question. What is not working? What error or unexpected behavior are you getting. What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks @Space_C0wb0y for -1 :). What was so complicated you could not understand? Have look at _tmain function body.

Comment: If there is something wrong with your program that means you either cannot compile it, or it does not behave as expected. If you cannot compile it, post the error you are getting. If the behavior is wrong, explain the expected behavior and how the actual behavior differs from it. Restrict the code you post the relevant passages, not the entire program.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope you get it.

Comment: @Manjoor: Hundreds of questions get asked on SO every day. Users that answer them usually neither have the time nor the motivation to read through large chunks of badly written code to find comments that indicate what might be wrong. If you want help, put some effort in asking the question, and you will be stunned by how much better the results will be.

Comment: I understand, it looks too long but i want to post complete working code. Again thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: People do not know the contents of WriteToSQL, how are we supposed to tell you why it didn't return 0?

Comment: If you think the problem is in converting a char * string to to wchar * string, show us that code only, and show us how it *doesn't* work.

Comment: For example, did you debug and look at the contents of wsql and find it doesn't contain what you expected?

Comment: I don't know what is the problem. I know one thing for sure that i can't do the same thing as L prefix is doing!!! After a lot searching i found that my input string need to be converted using MultiByteToWideChar. I did that but it still does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just cast a `char *` to `wchar_t *` and expect it to work. You must do proper conversion, for example using `MultiByteToWideChar` function.

And in general, be very careful with type casts, and in particular avoid using C-style casts in C++ programs. This very case is a good example of why: you told the compiler to shut up (`(SQLWCHAR *) sql`), and in return got a problem at runtime. Use casts only when you are absolutely sure you are doing the right thing, and know better than the compiler. Not surprisingly, such cases are relatively rare...

Comment: Thanks. Please help me to use MultiByteToWideChar to convert sql var

Comment: @Manjoor: `wchar_t wsql[500]; MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8, 0, sql, strlen(sql), wsql, sizeof wsql / sizeof *wsql ); printResult(WriteToSQL(wsql));`

Comment: Thanks, I have checked the code. MultiByteToWideChar is working fine but it does not work as the line SQLWCHAR * s1 = (SQLWCHAR *) L"INSERT INTO OE(sqltext) VALUES('this text')";   works. Please note L before string

Comment: @Manjoor: If MultiByteToWideChar is working fine, then what is actually the problem?

Comment: @Manjoor: Sorry for creating a confusion. Please change the fourth parameter to `strlen(sql) + 1`, and then it'll work. Sorry again for not writing that way in the first place.

Comment: MultiByteToWideChar doesn't return a C-string, it just returns the converted characters.  This means there's no terminating null.  Prefill the buffer with 0s.

Comment: @Donnie: Prefilling with 0s is an option, however as the input string is null-terminated, `strlen(sql) + 1` will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using wide chars the whole way?
Like this:

```
wchar_t input[100]; 
wchar_t sql[500];  

wprintf(L"Enter input string :: "); 
fgetws(input,100,stdin); 
for(int i=0;i<100;i++) 
    if(input[i]==10) 
        input[i]=0; 

wcscpy(sql,L"INSERT INTO OE(sqltext) VALUES('"); 
wcscat(sql,input); 
wcscat(sql,L"')"); 


if(WriteToSQL(sql) == 0)
  printf( "Success");     
else
  printf( "Failed");     // It failed
```

Warning:I did not test it, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Manjoor, by using _tmain you opted using generic text so be consistent and try to stick to generic-text types throughout your program. That way your code will be cleaner and you won't need to use nasty string conversions like MultiByteToWideChar. If you are in position to change WriteToSQL function signature, pass argument 's' as SQLTCHAR* type. Declare sql and input variables as TCHAR arrays, use string routines from TCHAR.H (e.g. _tprintf instead printf, _T() macro for hardcoded strings...). For each routine you are using, go to its MSDN page and check Generic-text routine mappings to see which one you should use.

Google for Microsoft's support for UNICODE in order to better understand issue you had in the example you provided.

Comment: I have edited the question to be specific to my problem. Please have a look

Comment: @Manjoor First make sure that MultiByteToWideChar does not fail - check its return error. If it fails, check its arguments - especially those regarding buffer size - they are most frequent source of errors in this type of functions. If it does not fail, use wprintf in WriteToSQL so you can see whether expected string is passed to that function.

Comment: It does not failed. After conversion i can see the value in my debug window

Comment: @Manjoor If you are sure that string passed to function is correct, then you need to look further - check the logic of the function itself. That string is a SQL command. Have you checked whether its format matches the one expected by DB? Single or double quotation marks? If you have access to another DB client, copy-paste this command string and try to run it there to make sure that command is correct.